# using pam_echo in sftp PAM configuration

Tags: sftp, pam

I'm using pam_echo in ssh pam configuration file.
For SSH logins, I'm able to see the content displayed by pam_echo but for sftp (which uses the same PAM stack) doesn't display anything on console.
Is it because stdout is redirected to some file in sftp? If you know please suggest a way to check this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The output is suppressed in `sftp`, because the stdio is used for the `sftp` protocol itself and does not allow you to pass any additional messages.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Is there any way I can reuse stdout to print some information? Eg., by enabling some configuration?
Also is this info documented somewhere?

Comment: No. It is not possible.

Comment: OK thank you very much